# Selenium IDE: Why "Element X = Y not found" message, despite successful execution of test step?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

Why does Selenium IDE give me the following error message, even when it successfully clicks on the UI button? I've tried all the available click, clickAndWait, Pause (pictured here), options I know of.

Exact Log:
[info] Executing: |click | class=button save | |
[error] Element class=button save not found

HTML:

```
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=login</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Add</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>class=icon-capability</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Capability</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>class=btn btn-primary</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=name</td>
    <td>secondly</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>name=create</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>class=button save</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my guess is the selector.  You are looking for `*[class='button save']`

If the element you are selecting is:

```
// doesn't match
<button id="something" class="save button"></button>

// matches
<button id="something_else" class="button save"></button>
```

My guess is that something dynamically is happening. Try matching on something more unique than a class.  If it has an ID attribute, use that.  If it doesn't have that and it has a `name` attribute, use that.

If it doesn't have anything to match on BUT the class, then try using CSS.

```
css=button.button.save
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem I believe was the
`<td>waitForElementPresent</td>
  <td>class=icon-capability</td>`
was not the correct command, and was not allowing the following step to execute because it was essentially waiting for the wrong element.